# Magento saving newly created order attribute value in the checkout

Tags: magento

I created a new order attribute. Code is as in below ;

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute('order', 'location', array(
    'position'             => 50,
    'type'              => 'text',
    'label'                => 'Location',
    'global'            => 1,
    'visible'           => 0,
    'required'          => 1,
    'user_defined'      => 1,
    'searchable'        => 0,
    'filterable'        => 1,
    'comparable'        => 1,
    'visible_on_front'  => 0,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => 0,
    'unique'            => 0,
    'is_configurable'   => 0,
    'position'          => 1,
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Then i need to save that attribute value in the checkout. I created a observer function for 'sales_order_save_before' action.

```
public function saveLocationOrderattributes(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        $locationid = '10';
        $order->setLocation($locationid);
        Mage::getSingleton('custommodule/custommodule')->saveLocationOrderattributes($order);
        return $this;
    }
```

Din not get any errors. Then i checked the value in order details. Nothing got.

Can anyone please tell me how to save attribute value for orders.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
  you can try the code: $order->save();
```

Comment: When i put that i got ann errr saying memory exceeded. Allocated memory is 168M